# Xamarin.Forms Navigation.PushAsync not working in ContentView

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, navigation

I want to navigate to other page in Xamarin Forms but it is not working in Content View. I am using

> await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2());

This code is not giving any error and run successfully but there is no effect on page. I am using this code in content  page also and it works properly there but it is not working in case of ContentView.
Currently I am using

> await ParentView.Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2());

and it is working fine in ContentView. But I am getting warning that "ParentView is obsolete as of version 2.1.0. Please use Parent instead.". But there is no function like

> await Parent.Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2());

and it is giving syntax error. So, is there any other way to navigate to other page using ContentView.

Comment: You could use `App.Current.MainPage`

Comment: @cvanbeek, It will not show Back button on Page2.

Comment: Sorry I meant call pushasync() from the MainPage

Comment: @cvanbeek, PushAsync is giving error and Navigation.PushAsync is not working.

Comment: Is it a syntax error? If your mainpage is a NavigationPage you can call (App.Current.MainPage as NavigationPage).PushAsync()

Comment: @cvanbeek Yes it works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem. Do you want me to add it as an answer?

Comment: @cvanbeek Yes please, it may also helps others.

Comment: the reason this doesn't work is that Navigation is a property of Page, and ContentView is not a Page.  ContentView Parent is also not guaranteed to be a Page, although you could probably cast it.

Comment: For me such problem appeared when i messed up things in my TabbedPage custom renderer. The tabbedPage was inside a navigatioPage and was my root. After a i fixed this PushAsync started working again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the `MainPage` of your app is a `NavigationPage`, then you can always call `PushAsync()` from inside your app.  I would recommend checking that the `MainPage` is of type `NavigationPage` just to be sure you don't throw a cast exception.  To do this, just use these two lines:

```
if(App.Current.MainPage is NavigationPage)
    (App.Current.Mainpage as NavigationPage).PushAsync(new Page2());
```

Answer (score 3):

the solution provided by cvanbeek don't work with mine problem but i sort out 
you have to use this in your c# code 
the problem is this you have to understand the hierarchy of code how it works 
use this to move to another page inside of ContentView .content property

```
 ((App.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage).Detail as NavigationPage).Navigation.PushAsync(new page());
```

Enjoy Folks :)

Comment: I was using MasterDetailPage, so yes, your solution worked for me.

Comment: Does anyone has an explanation why `Navigation.PushAsync()` doesn't work, but this? Ok, `Navigation` is only a proxy, but it still doesn't make sense for me. In my case `Navigation` worked in `Debug` mode, but not in `Release` mode.